# display span element if in certain post types

Tags: custom-post-types

On lines 4-6, I've inserted three conditional statements to determine which post type the post is in so I can insert a span which I will use to insert an image. The way I wrote it isn't working. What statement would I need to use? And is there a simpler way to set this up?

```
    <section id="main">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article class="search-post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php if (is_singular('projects')) {echo'<span class="search-projects"></span>';} ?>
            <?php if (is_singular('videos')) {echo'<span class="search-videos"></span>';} ?>
            <?php if (is_singular('friends')) {echo'<span class="search-friends"></span>';} ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <section class="search-entry">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </section>
        </article>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php my_paginate_links(); ?>
    </section>
```

For categories, I usually use `in_category`. Is there something like an `in_post_type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `is_singular()`, you're also checking for if it's a singular item on the page. Do `$post->post_type == 'my-post-type'` instead.

BTW: if you use `post_class()` you get this and more done automatically.

Comment: Actually according to Codex `is_singular()` with post type passed should check for that specific post type. I am not sure why would it fail in this specific case. **Edit** Scratch that, got confused for a moment. `is_singular()` check for global query, not global post. So not suitable for loop of multiple posts.